# Error UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionManager::GetCurrentReading_Internal

Tags: vuforia, hololens, mrtk

I am working to create a Hololens application using Vuforia for the Tracking system and MRTK for the interaction with the objects. The problem comes when mounting the solution in Visual Studio, I can not run because I get the following error. specifically a breakpoint in int32_t retVal = _il2cpp_icall_func (___ sourceStates0);

If I work separately, in principle I have no problems. but when I put them together, I get this error.

```cs
// System.Int32 UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionManager::GetCurrentReading_Internal(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState[])
extern "C" IL2CPP_METHOD_ATTR int32_t InteractionManager_GetCurrentReading_Internal_m48B784A597B956AF326A4DCB9C00F2AACF4C62A7 (InteractionSourceStateU5BU5D_tB8FF9D808295324B506769A009A5BD2C5CD671EA* ___sourceStates0, const RuntimeMethod* method)
{
    typedef int32_t (*InteractionManager_GetCurrentReading_Internal_m48B784A597B956AF326A4DCB9C00F2AACF4C62A7_ftn) (InteractionSourceStateU5BU5D_tB8FF9D808295324B506769A009A5BD2C5CD671EA*);
    static InteractionManager_GetCurrentReading_Internal_m48B784A597B956AF326A4DCB9C00F2AACF4C62A7_ftn _il2cpp_icall_func;
    if (!_il2cpp_icall_func)
    _il2cpp_icall_func = (InteractionManager_GetCurrentReading_Internal_m48B784A597B956AF326A4DCB9C00F2AACF4C62A7_ftn)il2cpp_codegen_resolve_icall ("UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionManager::GetCurrentReading_Internal(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState[])");
    int32_t retVal = _il2cpp_icall_func(___sourceStates0);
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Unity, MRTK and Vuforia are you using? This is an error inside of Unity and knowing the specific versions may help identify the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Unity 2018.3.2.f1  -- Vuforia 7.5.26  --  MRTK v2.0.0-RC1-Refresh